# How to output 3 objects as 3 seperate nodes in a g3dj file

Tags: export, node-editor

I have three obj files: a ship, a turret and a gun.
I want to import these back into Blender and output such that the g3DJ file contains three seperate "nodes" (as achieved by Xoppa of libgdx fame - probably using Maya).
All I get is one node with "children" having 3 "parts".
How do I achieve seperate "node" output?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
I was exporting from blender to a wavefront obj file and then using fbx-conv to convert to a G3DJ one: this gave one node with 1 children with 3 parts.
Now when I export to an fbx file and convert to G3DJ using fbx-conv I get 3 nodes as required.